# Easy way of computing $\iint\limits_{B_R(0)} (e^y+e^{-y})\cos(x) d(x,y)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

So I was asked to compute the integral

$$\iint\limits_{B_R(0)} (e^y+e^{-y})\cos(x) \, d(x,y), \qquad B_R(0):=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid x^2+y^2\leq R\}$$

the explicit way and the apparent "easy" way where no calculation is needed.

I did the first part but I fail to see the easy way to compute this.

Can anyone give me a hint? Thanks

Comment: Notice any symmetries in the integral? Like parity?

Comment: @AlphaNumeric the integrand is even in both variables, so you can integrate over the 1st quadrant and multiply the result by 4 -- how does it make it easy?

Comment: The integrand is a harmonic function, so, by the mean value property...

Comment: You can also use complex analysis and realize that $\cosh(y)\cosh(ix)=\Re(\cosh(y+ix))$ and $$\int_{B_R(0)} \cosh(y+ix) \, {\rm d}x {\rm d}y = \int_0^R 2\pi r \, {\rm d}r \, \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} {\rm d}\phi \cosh(r e^{i\phi}) \, .$$

Comment: Thanks, I've used the mean-value property to get 

$$\iint\limits_{B_R(0)}(e^y+e^{-y})\cos(x)\,d(x,y)=\|B_R(0)\|\cdot(e^0+e^{-0})\cos(0)=\frac{8\pi R^3}{3}$$

Comment: @HannahBloom Numerically, for $\displaystyle R = 1$: LHS  $\displaystyle \approx 6.2832$. Your RHS  $\displaystyle \approx\require{cancel} \cancel{8.3776}$.

Comment: The only mistake on @HannahBloom's part was forgetting this is a $2$-dimensional ball, so $\Vert B_R(0)\Vert=\pi R^2$. So the original problem's solution is $2\pi R^2$. Dimensional analysis would have exposed this.

Comment: @J.G. Yeah I realized shortly after that I went one dimension too high, just forgot about editing the answer. Thanks for pointing it out though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consolidating several comments, the integrand is $2\Re\cos(x+iy)$, so a change to polar coordinates lets us apply the [mean value property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function#The_mean_value_property) viz.$$2\int_0^Rrdr\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta\cos(re^{i\theta})=2\int_0^Rrdr\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta1=2\pi R^2.$$As an alternative to the MVP, we can expand $\cos z$ as its Taylor series, using $\int_0^{2\pi}e^{ik\theta}d\theta=2\pi\delta_{k0}$ for $k\in\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\iint_{x^{2} + y^{2} < R^{2}}
\pars{\expo{y} + \expo{-y}}\cos\pars{x}\,\dd x\,\dd y}
\\[5mm] = &\
\iint_{\large\mathbb{R}^{2}}
\pars{\expo{y} + \expo{-y}}\cos\pars{x}
\bracks{R^{2} - x^{2} - y^{2} > 0}\,\dd x\,\dd y
\\[5mm] = &\
\iint_{\large\mathbb{R}^{2}}
\pars{\expo{y} + \expo{-y}}\cos\pars{x}
\bracks{\int_{0^{+} - \infty\ic}^{0^{+} + \infty\ic}
{\expo{\pars{R^{2} - x^{2} - y^{2}}s} \over s}
\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}}\dd x\,\dd y
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0^{+} - \infty\ic}^{0^{+} + \infty\ic}
{\expo{R^{2}s} \over s}
\overbrace{\bracks{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\cos\pars{x}\expo{-sx^{2}}\dd x}}^{\ds{\root{\pi}\,{\expo{-1/\pars{4s}} \over \root{s}}}}\ \times
\\[2mm] &\
\phantom{\int_{0^{+} - \infty\ic}^{0^{+} + \infty\ic}
{\expo{R^{2}s} \over s}\,\,}
\underbrace{\bracks{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\expo{-sy^{2} + y}\dd y +
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\expo{-sy^{2} - y}\dd y}}
_{\ds{2\root{\pi}\,{\expo{1/\pars{4s}} \over \root{s}}}}
{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\ic\int_{0^{+} - \infty\ic}^{0^{+} + \infty\ic}
{\expo{R^{2}s} \over s^{2}}\,\dd s =
-\ic\bracks{2\pi\ic\,\lim_{s \to 0}\totald{\expo{R^{2}s}}{s}} =
\bbx{\large 2\pi R^{2}} \\ &
\end{align}